# Increasing efficiency of run-time complexity of comparing vector elements?

Tags: c++, big-o

I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> V1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::vector<int> V2 {1,2,3};
```

Executing the following would result in quadratic run-time complexity:

```
for(auto IT = V1.begin(); IT != V1.end(), IT++)
{
  for(auto IT2 = V2.begin(); IT2 != V2.end(); IT2++)
  {
    if(*IT == *IT2){std::cout<<"Found a match!"<<std::endl;}
    else{std::cout<<"No match!"<<std::endl;}

  }
}
```

Are there any clear ways to bring this down to linear time?

Would using an STL algorithm enable this?

For instance:

```
for(auto IT = V1.begin(); IT != V1.end(); IT++)
{
  std::find(V2.begin(), V2.end(), *IT);
}
```

Comment: Define what "comparing vector elements" mean to you. Specifically explain the expected results when either vector contains duplicate values.

Comment: If you know your vectors are ordered a binary search is faster.

Comment: maybe use std:: set and compare sets? The red-black trees inside sets and maps give excellent performance and fit use cases similar to yours. Or, as suggested, sort the vectors first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need to keep one array at linear time (your source array as you're obviously searching from it's 0th to it's Nth element).

However, you **can** bring the other search term down by ensuring that the contents of the search space are sorted first.  This will allow the use of binary search algorithms which are log(n) complexity.

Good luck!

An example of this:

```
std::vector<int> V1 {1,4,5,6,3};
std::vector<int> V2 {100, 104,101,3};
bool condition {false};
std::sort(V2.begin(), V2.end());

for(auto IT = V1.begin(); IT != V1.end(); IT++)
{
  auto result {std::binary_search(V2.begin(), V2.end(), *IT)};
  if(result > 0){ condition = true};
}
```

Comment: Monza is my edit okay with you? anything you want to add?

Comment: Just want to add that, its always better to sort the vector with less number of elements while doing intersection of 2 vectors.